git - fixing 'bad tree object', that doesn't exist and nothing points to it
We have a central git repo, that started to tell us after every push, that it can't do gc. When connection to it with SSH, and trying to run gc we get:
$ git gc
fatal: bad tree object 7561107eb53a58dc907f0cc8dac75f18ccecd3ae
fatal: failed to run repack

But we can't find this object, nor nothing that points to it.
We know it doesn't exist because:

git cat-file --batch-check --batch-all-objects --unordered | grep 7561107eb53a58dc907f0cc8dac75f18ccecd3ae returns nothing
fsck command (git fsck --unreachable or --dangling or --lost-found, or --full) returns nothing with it
also this: git fsck 7561107eb53a58dc907f0cc8dac75f18ccecd3ae >> ... error: 7561107eb53a58dc907f0cc8dac75f18ccecd3ae: object missing
and this git cat-file -p 7561107eb53a58dc907f0cc8dac75f18ccecd3ae >> fatal: Not a valid object name 7561107eb53a58dc907f0cc8dac75f18ccecd3ae

We know that no-one points to it, because when iterating all the objs and inspecting their content (to find which one points to it) with git cat-file --batch --batch-all-objects --unordered | grep 7561107eb53a58dc907f0cc8dac75f18ccecd3ae we get empty results.
But still we get error on each git gc. How can we find the culprit?

Did you try to just search for it in all the files? grep -RF 7561107eb53a58dc907f0cc8dac75f18ccecd3ae .git

@CherryDT: Now I tried. I get nothing, besides the gc.log file (that is created after each push if we delete it) "./gc.log:fatal: bad tree object 7561107eb53a58dc907f0cc8dac75f18ccecd3ae"
